# How to get the substring of a filename that matches a "*" glob wildcard?

Tags: bash, wildcards

Lets say that I have a directory with the following files (among others):

```
touch doc-mike.txt doc-jane.txt doc-susan.txt
```

I can do something in a script with those files using a construct like:

```
for fname in doc-*.txt; do
    echo input: ${fname}
done
```

But if I want to get the substring of the filename that matches the wildcard I have to jump through some ugly hoops:

```
for fname in doc-*.txt; do
    wildcard=${fname#doc-}
    wildcard=${wildcard%.txt}

    echo input: ${fname} output: output-${wildcard}.results
done
```

That works:

```
input: doc-jane.txt output: output-jane.results
input: doc-mike.txt output: output-mike.results
input: doc-susan.txt output: output-susan.results
```

but I feel like there has to be a better/easier way to get the substring that matches the `"*"` glob wildcard

Comment: What's "ugly" about those "hoops"? It would additionally work in any POSIX shell. The only thing is that you need to quote your variable expansions properly.

Comment: to add a `shopt -s nullglob` at the top and a `shopt -u nullglob` after would be useful but only in bash.

Comment: The top of the list of what I dislike probably starts with: 1) I have to use two expressions instead of one, 2) i need an intermediate variable (the first expressions acts directly on `$fname` - the second expression can't do the same), and 3) the things I'm matching in those two expressions are themselves fragments of stuff I want excluded - it's not readily apparent to me what I actually *want* from those expressions

Comment: Using a regular expression match like muru shows in his answer works, but is a far more complicated way of doing it, and also uses an extra variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest I can think of is `BASH_REMATCH`, since bash stores the results of a regex text in the that variable:

```
$ for fname in doc-*.txt; do 
    [[ $fname =~ doc-(.*).txt ]];
    echo "input: ${fname} output: output-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.results";
done
input: doc-jane.txt output: output-jane.results
input: doc-mike.txt output: output-mike.results
input: doc-susan.txt output: output-susan.results
```

As `(.*)` is the first group in the regex, it's in `BASH_REMATCH[1]`. I think this is the behaviour you want, but with globs, I don't think bash makes that available in any way.

Comment: You could also do something like `for fname in *; do [[ $fname =~ doc-(.*).txt ]] || continue; ... ; done` to avoid duplicating the pattern

Comment: Be advised that the glob `*` represents `[^/]` as a regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh` you can use a mix of [glob qualifiers, history expansion modifiers and globbing flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) to do it.
Assuming you have enabled extended globbing and history pattern substitution mode via

```
setopt extendedglob
setopt histsubstpattern
```

you can then run

```
print doc-*.txt(#q:s/(#b)doc-(*).txt/'${match[1]}'/)
```

which will output

```
jane mike susan
```

As usual, you can combine this with other qualifiers/modifiers/flags e.g. select only regular files, anchor the expression to beginning/end of word etc.

---

Though if you wanted to iterate over each file name, with `zsh` you can nest parameter expansions so your code could be simplified to

```
for fname in doc-*.txt; do
    print input: ${fname} output: output-${${fname#doc-}%.txt}.results
done
```

The above (re:[your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436133/how-to-get-the-substring-of-a-filename-that-matches-a-glob-wildcard/436201#comment787906_436133)) uses a single expression and doesn't need an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
for fname in doc-*.txt; do 
  echo "input: ${fname} output: output-${fname:4:$((${#fname}-8))}.results"
done
```