# Bash regex named capture groups with backreference?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I want to do below -

```
bash-shell>echo (*).prop ; echo \1
```

Obviously above does not work. But want to know if it is possible and what would be the working equivalent.

I want `*` (for shell this the wild card) to match all the files in the current directory. And ofcourse limit the above search to only files ending with .prop.
Capture the filename with out .prop extension and print it using backreference `\1`

The example i added is bit simple just for explanation sake. My usecase is little more involved, but what I need is backreference to meet my requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the substring of a filename that matches a "\*" glob wildcard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436133/how-to-get-the-substring-of-a-filename-that-matches-a-glob-wildcard)

Comment: will this combination not work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-bash and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

ksh93 is the only shell that supports back references in globs AFAIK, and ksh93 and zsh support capture groups which is more like what you're looking for here, but even then, you couldn't use it as you propose. That `\1` (ksh93) or `$match[1]` (zsh) would need refer to what was captured for each matching file.

In ksh93, you can do:

```
files=( ~(N)*.prop )
(( ${#files[@]} == 0 )) || printf '%s\n' "${files[@]/@(*).prop/\1}"
```

In zsh:

```
set -o extendedglob
files=( *.prop(N) )
print -rC1 -- ${files/(#b)(*).prop/$match[1]}
```

Where the reference to the capture group is done for each matching file as part of the `${array/pattern/replacement}` operator.

With `zsh`, that can also be done as part of the `e`val glob qualifier:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- *.prop(Ne['REPLY=${REPLY/(#b)(*).prop/$match[1]}'])
```

Though there's a dedicated `:r`ootname modifier to remove extensions:

```
print -rC1 -- *.prop(N:r)
```

In bash, you could always do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( *.prop )
(( ${#files[@]} == 0 )) ||
  printf '%s\n' "${files[@]%.prop}"
```

Back references are a feature of basic regular expressions, and a few other regular expression engines.

`bash` does have a builtin regular expression matching operator, but note that it uses extended regular expressions (EREs). Standard EREs don't do back-references, even though some implementations support it as an extension.

In:

```
[[ aa =~ (.)\1 ]]
```

Doesn't work not so much because `\1` is not a standard ERE operator, but because bash treats that `\1` as a quoted `1`, so invokes the system's regexp engine with `(.)1` as the regexp.

```
regexp='(.)\1'
[[ aa =~ $regex ]]
```

Would work though on systems where the extended regexp engine supports back-references such as on GNU systems.

Here, it's more capturing you want though, and bash does do that.

After a successful

```
[[ $file =~ ^(.*)\.prop$ ]]
```

What is matched by `(.*)` will be available in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` (the second element of the `$BASH_REMATCH` array; in zsh what's captured goes into the `$match` array), so you could do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.prop; do
  if [[ $file =~ ^(.*)\.prop$ ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi
done
```

(note that it's possible for `*.prop` to come up with a file where `[[ $file =~ ^(.*)\.prop$ ]]` fails, like when the file's name is not encoded in the user's locale charset).

---

In any case, in POSIX shells, `\1` is the same as `'1'` or `"1"`, that's a quoted `1`. So shells that aim for POSIX compliance can only give it a different meaning in areas not specified by POSIX like in `print -r -- @(?)\1*` in ksh93 to find files that start with two identical characters (where those unquoted `(`, `)` yield unspecified behaviour) or that `"${files[@]/@(*).prop/\1}"` mentioned earlier where `${array/pattern/replacement}` is not an operator specified by POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `basename` (or `basename` on FreeBSD or any other implementation that gives you the non-standard `-a` and `-s` options for handling more than a single argument and for removing the suffix from each of those arguments):

```bash
basename -a -s .prop -- *.prop
```

This would give you the names of the files that match the pattern `*.prop`, but with their `.prop` filename suffix removed.

Using a way similar to what you suggest:

```bash
names=( *.prop )
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]%.prop}"
```

This creates an array, `names`, containing all the matching names.  The variable substitution used with `printf` then removes the `.prop` filename suffix from each name before `printf` outputs them.

Since we know that the array only contains strings ending in `.prop`, that second line could be shortened to

```bash
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]%.*}"
```

This would remove anything after the last dot (and the dot) in each string in the `names` array.

The shell doesn't really use regular expressions for matching filenames.  It's done with filename globbing patterns.  Regular expressions are more often used to match text in files.

Comment: The example i added is bit simple just for explanation sake. My usecase is little more involved, but what I need is backreference to meet my requirement.

Comment: @samshers We can't help you with things you don't mention in the question.